# Why program output produces 1 / 0 error

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"];    
    f[k_] := (4^k (4^k - 1.) Abs[BernoulliB[2 k]])/(2 k)!;
    data = Table[1/Power[f[n], (2 n - 1)^-1], {n, 1, 300}];
    ListPlot[data, PlotLabel -> $Version]
```

But a 1 / 0 error warning (`Power::infy`) was generated.

Comment: if you replace `4^k - 1.` with `4^k - 1` the error message goes away (Version 11.3 Windows 10-64bit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But a 0 / 1 error warning was generated.

The error is 1/0 and not 0/1, it happened because you used machine floating point numbers.

```
f[k_] := (4^k (4^k - 1.) Abs[BernoulliB[2 k]])/(2 k)!;
n = 89;
1/Power[f[n], (2 n - 1)^-1]
```

gives

```
 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision \
 may be lost
 Power::infy
```

But if you change the function to use exact numbers

```
f[k_] := (4^k (4^k - 1) Abs[BernoulliB[2 k]])/(2 k)!;
n = 89;
1/Power[f[n], (2 n - 1)^-1]
```

The error goes away

```
 ListPlot[data, PlotLabel -> $Version]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now works